# Python elementtree and mutability

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong with Python (2.7) here?

I am using element trees to store XML data. My class constructor takes a class instance with element tree attribute (sw is the class insance, sw.instance is the element tree) as a parameter, adds an element to it and stores it in a class variable self.software. This is the class constructor:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElT
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, bd, sw, name):
        itmp = sw.instance
        print "before %s" % ElT.tostring(itmp)
        y = ElT.SubElement(itmp, "name")
        y.text = name
        self.software = itmp
        print "after %s" % ElT.tostring(sw.instance)
```

The problem is, in addition of storing the modified sw to self.software, it also changes sw.instance. So when I use this to create two classes

```
foo = MyClass(x, mysoftwareclass, "foo")
bar = MyClass(y, mysoftwareclass, "bar")
```

the foo instance is fine but bar instance contains two "name" elements. The first call to MyClass appears to modify the mysoftwareclass instance. I have confirmed this with the before and after print statements.

I sort of thought mysoftwareclass would be immutable when called like this.  I can of course use a workaround and create two identical software class instances, to pass one to foo and one to bar, but I am curious what happens here.

Comment: Why would you think it would be immutable? The same object is being passed into two classes, so naturally changing it in one place changes it in another.

Comment: Because I do not edit sw.instance but a copy of it (itmp = sw.instance and modifications done to itmp)

Comment: No, that's not a copy. I'm still not sure why you think it is. `itmp` and `sw.instance` are two references to the same object, `self.software` is yet another reference to it.

Comment: What is then the correct way of taking in something as read only, and creating a local copy in the constructor to allow modifications without changing anything in the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. copy.deepcopy. How stupid of me.